# Three.js: Set 6 Cube Panorama to Any Side (Front, Back, Left, etc.)

Tags: javascript, three.js, vertex-shader

I am using this example for my project that rotates 6 cube panorama image:

https://threejs.org/examples/?q=panora#webgl_panorama_cube
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_panorama_cube.html

```
scene = new THREE.Scene();
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 90, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 100 );
camera.position.z = 0.01;

var skyBox = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.CubeGeometry( 1, 1, 1 ), materials );
skyBox.geometry.scale( 1, 1, - 1 );
scene.add( skyBox );
```

The cube has 6 sides: FRONT, BACK, LEFT, RIGHT, BOTTOM, TOP.

`THREE.Raycaster` allows me to detect current cube side during user's rotation around the panorama cubes utilizing `intersectObjects`.

However, on initial panorama load, I want to be able to set any specified cube (FRONT, BACK, LEFT, or RIGHT) as initial point. For example, I always get BACK side initially, but based on user's settings, I want to be able to force it to FRONT, LEFT, or RIGHT side.

I could not find the way to do it except maybe playing around with `THREE.Camera.position.y` setting. Adding the right value for it must point to side's very center. If this is the right approach, how to calculate it the right way?

Answer (score 0):

You can rotate your skybox geometry quarter-turns by using a pattern like so:

```
skyBox.geometry.rotateY( value * Math.PI / 2 ); // value = 0, 1, 2, or 3
```

Alternatively, you can rotate the skybox mesh:

```
skyBox.rotation.y = ( value * Math.PI / 2 ); // .x and .z rotation = 0
```

three.js r.93

Comment: Thank you. It seems to revert the index of sides but I am visually landing on the same side. In both solutions. So, it does not work for me :(